# C# Check if a csv calendar file belong to Google

Tags: c#, csv, google-calendar-api

Just for curious, is there any smarter way to check if a calendar CSV file was a google calendar CSV file?

I check it with the first line:

```
if (firstLine
      .Contains("Subject,Start Date,Start Time,End Date,End Time,
                    All Day Event,Description,Location"))
```

But I thought that it was not so smart.
Is there any smarter way to check? Or I just can check with the first line?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If the file has informations about creator you can get that but i don't think it has. So probably, you can only check if it made from template or not. Even they change "Subject" to "Subjeck" your program will detect it as unknown file.

Comment: @Neenhila Sure, I am afraid of that... If the first line changed to avoid checking, I had no way to check it. Even I can use ```.IndexOf()``` regardless of case, it still cannot be useful very much.

Comment: You can use multiple validation. May it can save you. If accurate is more than %80 like 4 items is nice but 5th one is corrupted but you can say its still google's.

Comment: @Neenhila Thanks...This might save some of me. Fortunately, this check is not too important. It is just based on my curiosity to see if there are other methods. In addition, I checked later and found that no creator was found in the csv files in either of the general calendar or the Google Calendar, which was a bit regretful.